# MySql database table having Xml String. How to Import that data into another mysql Table

Tags: java, mysql, xml, database

I have one Person named table's. this table's column "outsourcedData" contain below xml as an String :

```
<person>
    <educations total="2">
        <education>
            <school-name>Delhi University</school-name>
            <degree>Master of Science (MSc)</degree>
            <field-of-study>Banking and Financial Support Services</field-of-study>
            <start-date>
                <year>2009</year>
            </start-date>
            <end-date>
                <year>2013</year>
            </end-date>
        </education>
        <education>
            <school-name>American University</school-name>
            <degree>Bachelor of Arts (BA)</degree>
            <field-of-study>Business Administration and Management, General</field-of-study>
        </education>
    </educations>
</person>
```

There are lots of similar rows available into this table. Is there is any way  so I can load these    data parse and insert into education table.

```
There are lots of row I am having in my database. But now I want to import this data into new table Education which I newly created in database corresponding fields with xml.(SchoolName,degree......).
```

In Mysql Database what is the best way to migrate this database.
I am stuck in this  place. Please help. help

```
create table person (id int,outersource varchar(1024));
insert into person values(1,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><person><educations total="2"><education><school-name>Delhi University</school-name><degree>Master of Science (MSc)</degree><field-of-study>Banking and Financial Support Services</field-of-study><start-date><year>2009</year></start-date><end-date><year>2013</year></end-date></education><education><school-name>American University</school-name><degree>Bachelor of Arts (BA)</degree><field-of-study>Business Administration and Management, General</field-of-study></education></educations></person>');
create table education( schoolName varchar(255), degree varchar(255),start_year datetime, end_year datetime);
```

Any Store Procedure we can do this  ?

Comment: Just do an update in JOIN,but it`s hard to know which is what from your question.

Comment: My One Table having data. That table contain XML String as well as  i show here. I can fire select query on  this  table. Now I hv create a new table Education. In this new table i  want to migrate my previous XML data which was available in form XML string in that table

Comment: Create a new column in the education table and then `INSERT INTO education(newColumn) SELECT oldColumn FROM MyOneTable`

Comment: I don't want to repeat that xml  string into Education table. I want to Parse that Xml String and than insert into Education table. one to one value into education table.

Comment: Hope now you able getting my exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Originally problem  was  that. I have three tables. first table where xml string data  exist and two new table for this xml string parsing. Parent table contain school name + userid  unique combinate. during parsing xml if any node contain same  school name +  user id than data saved into child table.
this child table having referece  of this parent table. use below stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`teneqs`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `xxx`()
begin
    declare v_row_index int unsigned default 0;
    declare v_row_count int unsigned;
    declare v_xpath_row varchar(255);
    declare userId int;
    declare userEduInfoId int;
    declare p_xml   text;
    declare p_xpath_row varchar(255) default '//educations[1]/education';
 declare done int;


DECLARE outsourcedUserDataCursor CURSOR FOR  select user_id, data from source_table where sourceType='LINKED_IN' order by user_id;
OPEN outsourcedUserDataCursor;
 outsourcedUserDataCursor_loop:
        LOOP FETCH outsourcedUserDataCursor INTO userId,p_xml;
       Set v_row_index := 0;
       -- SET done := 0;
       select userId,p_xml;
    -- calculate the number of row elements.
     set v_row_count := extractValue(
            p_xml
        ,   concat(
                'count('
            ,   p_xpath_row
            ,   ')'
            )
        );
select v_row_count as  "Education  Count" ;
        IF v_row_count > 0 THEN
            -- loop through all the row elements
            while v_row_index < v_row_count do       
                set v_row_index := v_row_index + 1;
                set v_xpath_row := concat(
                    p_xpath_row
                ,   '['
                ,   v_row_index
                ,   ']'
                );
                select v_row_index, v_xpath_row;
                begin                
                 DECLARE userEduInfoCursor CURSOR FOR  select id from parent where user_id= userId and school_name=extractValue(p_xml,concat(v_xpath_row,'/school-name[1]')) limit 1;
                 -- DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
                 select "Exist into Edu Info table: ",userId,extractValue(p_xml,concat(v_xpath_row,'/school-name[1]')) as 'SchoolName';                 
                 OPEN userEduInfoCursor;
                 -- IF done = 1 THEN
                        -- select done "Done";
                 -- END IF;
                 select 'userEduInfoCursor will be open';
                        LOOP
                        FETCH userEduInfoCursor INTO userEduInfoId;
                        select userEduInfoId;
                            IF userEduInfoId is NOT NULL then
                            select "in side if, userid is not null";
                            -- Insert UserEducationInfo
                                insert into child(
                                        a
                                        ,b
                                        ,c
                                        ,d
                                        ,e
                                        ,f
                                        ,g
                                        ,h
                                        ,i
                                        ,j
                                    ) values(
                                        userID
                                        ,userEduInfoId
                                        ,extractValue(p_xml,concat(v_xpath_row,'/school-name[1]'))
                                        ,'degree'
                                        ,'fieldOfStudy'
                                        ,'January'
                                        ,'2001'
                                        ,'December'
                                        ,'2014'
                                        ,'description');
                            ELSE
                            select "in side else";
                                close userEduInfoCursor;
                                -- User Info Inserted.
                                insert into parent (
                                    school_name
                                    ,user_id,
                                    creationDate,
                                    lastmodified) 
                                values (
                                    extractValue(p_xml,concat(v_xpath_row,'/school-name[1]'))
                                    ,userId
                                    ,now()
                                    ,now()
                                );

                                OPEN userEduInfoCursor;
                                FETCH userEduInfoCursor INTO userEduInfoId;
                                -- Detaild Information Entered

                              insert into child(
                                        a
                                        ,b
                                        ,c
                                        ,d
                                        ,e
                                        ,f
                                        ,g
                                        ,h
                                        ,i
                                        ,j
                                    ) values(
                                        userID
                                        ,userEduInfoId
                                        ,extractValue(p_xml,concat(v_xpath_row,'/school-name[1]'))
                                        ,'degree'
                                        ,'fieldOfStudy'
                                        ,'January'
                                        ,'2001'
                                        ,'December'
                                        ,'2014'
                                        ,'description');
                        END IF; 
                    END Loop;
                 close userEduInfoCursor;
                end;
                -- check userid  & school name already exist into info table -> insert into details  table. 

            end while;
        END IF;
    end LOOP outsourcedUserDataCursor_loop;
close outsourcedUserDataCursor;
end
```

I tired with this store procedure but there one issue with this. Only one single record insert into Parent table remaing other records inserted into another child table.
Please correct me where i did mistake.